# Angular Material mat-select doesn't work with browser autofill

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular-material

[image]I have an address form in my Angular 5 application with city, region, country, zip and etc fields.
Country and region are using Angular Material mat-select. And it doesn't work with Chrome browser autofill.

There is an example of code (but it's a simple mat-select):

```html
<mat-select
    [(ngModel)]="address.country"
    name="country"
    placeholder="Country"
    aria-label="Country"
    (change)="changeCountry()"
    autocomplete="country">

  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.name">
    <span>{{ country.name }}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

As I know material sets autocomplete attribute to 'off' by default, maybe it's a reason?

I would be glad of any help. Thank you.

Angular Material v. 5.2.5

Angular v. 5

Google Chrome v. 67.0.3396.99

Comment: Could you explain what exactly does not work?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="address.country"` should be an object same from `countries` array.

Comment: Show your script code - especially 'address.country', 'changeCountry()' and 'countries'.

Comment: @kemsky, this mat-select doesn't autofill with Chrome autofill address suggestion. Added screenshot to the question.

Comment: mat-select is not standard type of input it will not work with autofill

Comment: @kemsky thank you for your answer.

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48181367/) could be helpful

Comment: See if this solution helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60011526/5511725!!!